# Removing a column from a data table that was dynamically created

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I have a data table whose Rows and Columns have been defined and filled as

```
 table = new System.Data.DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Object ID");
            foreach (string column in columns)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(column);
            }
            foreach (string row in rows)
            { 
                drow = table.NewRow();
                tit = row.Substring(0, row.IndexOf('$'));
                drow[0] = tit.IndexOf('&') > -1 ? tit.Substring(tit.IndexOf('&') + 1) : tit;
                table.Rows.Add(drow);

            }
            //here i am displaying the data table on a grid.
            grid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

The data of the datatable is populated by a method.

I need to delete a column from the displayed data table.

I tried

```
table.Columns.RemoveAt(1);  //i put 1 there as a test
```

The data displayed in that column is deleted however not the column header.
How can I delete the header also ?

Comment: Your code should work as expected. Please be more clear on the issue you are encountering.

Comment: @Alberto , The column header is NOT being deleted. Which means I get a column with a header but no data in rows below it.

Comment: But where? In the debugger visualizer?

Comment: On the GRID on which it is being displayed.

Comment: Your datatable is bound to a wpf datagrid? If so, show us how the binding is done.

Comment: After removing Column from DataTable you have to Rebind DataTable to dataGeridView, And try use `grid.DataSource = table` for binding DataTable to DataGrid